# InputSystem.onAnyButtonPress.Call() is throwing error about StateEvent

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using the new input system in Unity 2021.3.1f1.

I made a simple script that detect all inputs made by the player:

```
private void Start()
    {
      InputSystem.onAnyButtonPress.Call(inputControl =>
      {
        DoSomething(); // Could be void, this is not the root of the issue
      });
    }
```

And I have the following errors:

```
ArgumentException: Event must be a StateEvent or DeltaStateEvent but is a TEXT instead
Parameter name: eventPtr

ArgumentException while executing 'InputSystem.onEvent' callbacks
```

Any idea from where it might come from?

Thanks in advance and have a good day !

Comment: Show your DoSomething  method

Comment: I remove the DoSomething() function, the errors appear in both cases

Answer (score 0):

According to ChangeLog for version 1.4.1, available here https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.4/changelog/CHANGELOG.html

There was a fix in the last version about this specific issue:

> Fixed InputSystem.onAnyButtonPress so that it doesn't throw exceptions
> when trying to process non state or delta events (case 1376034).

I don't know why Unity didn't installed me the last version but it works to update to last version !